# ¿Como puedo añadir mas de un elemento a un array en django?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-forms

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy probando django con mongodb para eso utilizo djongo y quiero enviarle por medio de un template varios elementos a una lista que esta dentro de un modelo pero no me deja registrar mas de un elemento.¿como puedo dar solucion a este problema?

Hasta el momento llevo esto:

Gracias por su ayuda...

Modelo:

```
from djongo import models
from django import forms


class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class AuthorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = (
            'name', 'email'
        )

class Entry(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
    authors = models.ArrayModelField(
        model_container=Author,
        model_form_class=AuthorForm
    )
    objects = models.DjongoManager()
```

Form:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Entry

class EntryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Entry
        fields = '__all__'
```

Vista :

```
def prueba2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            entrada = form.save(commit=False)
            entrada.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = EntryForm()


    template = loader.get_template('hola.html')

    context = {
        'form' : form
        }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context,request))   }
```

Template:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form }}

    {% for hidden in form.authors %}
      {{ hidden }}
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```